# Finding the next 5 posts

Tags: wp-query, query

On my single.php where I am calling my post I am wanting to run a query where I can catch the next 5 posts (chronologically). I know how to do everything except figure out a way to specify the 5 specific posts to be the posts created after my current post. using previous_post_link(); and next_post_link(); will not be relevant here as I need them to be category specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral part is using a `date_query` in a custom `WP_Query` to fetch the adjacent posts according to the parameters passed to it. Here is an idea coming from a plugin I'm busy with

To accomplish what you need, you'll need the following

- The current post object to get the `post_date` and `ID`
- The categories assigned to the current post.

The first part can be accomplished with `get_queried_object()` which will hold the `post_date` and `ID`. The latter part can be accomplished with `wp_get_post_terms()` for effiency

Putting it all together, you can try the following: (*CAVEAT: This is all untested and might be buggy, posting from a tablet*)

```
$post_object = get_queried_object();
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_object->ID, 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ); // Set fields to get only term ID's to make this more effient

$args = array(
    'cat' => $terms[0],
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'no_found_rows' => true,   // Get 5 poss and bail. Make our query more effiecient
    'suppress_filters' => true,  // We don't want any filters to alter this query
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => $post_object->post_date,  // Get posts after the current post, use current post post_date
            'inclusive' => false, // Don't include the current post in the query
        )
    ) 
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump( $q->posts );
```

### FEW IMPORTANT NOTES

- You need to play around with `after` and `before` in your `date_query` and with the `order` parameter. I cannot remember from the top of my head how I put this piece togther, shame on me. I think if you use `before` in your `date_query`, you need to set `order` to `ASC` to get the correct posts. But as I said, play around with those parameters
- I have used the default taxonomy `category` in my example. If you are using a custom taxonomy, change `category` in `wp_get_post_terms()` to your desired taxonomy name. Also, remove the `cat` parameter in the query arguments and replace it with a proper `tax_query`
- If you are only interested in getting post ID's, then you can set `'fields' => 'ids'`  in your query arguments to make your query more effient as well

This should give you a basic idea and this should help you to achieve your goal

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for taking the time Pieter. Do you have a donations page where I can buy you a beer?

Comment: Hahaha, great that my answer helped you in some way :-). Your positive feedback is more than enough for me, appreciated. Enjoy, and have that next beer on me. :-)

Comment: Im having an issue with this where it's not getting the immediate next posts -- IE, I'm on Post#1 and I want to get posts #2,3,4. This query is getting me posts #4,5,6.

Comment: like @Prefix mentioned, this will get the 5 most recent posts after the post you want. if you want the next 5 adjacent posts add the param 'order' => 'ASC'